# Is there a respectful way to dispose of a Quran?

Tags: quran

If I have an old, battered translation of the Qur'an is there a respectful way to dispose of it? I have read that one could burn it, however, I'm not sure if this is really true.

Comment: I found this link helpful : [Disposal of Quran](http://islam.about.com/od/quran/a/Disposal-Of-Quran.htm)

Answer (score 1):

**You could clean it by a clean cloth. If you want to remove the dust ...**

*Of course as far as I know, the best way to wipe out the papers which consist of Allah name, is putting the papers on the water. (River or ...)*

**but burning them would be a Haram act (definitely). Because using from fire for ...? Oh, Astaqferullah, recently I have heard that some people mention firing holy names or Quran..., Oh, to be honest I dont know what  their intention is, but rationally and also in accordance to all Shia scholars it is counted as a Haram act. since this is quite an insulting act.**